# function not calling or firing

Tags: javascript, function

I checked the debugger on chrome and I couldn't spot any errors.

I have combined all my functions into one in order to make the call easier to read.

```js
   
function runAll() {
    var validation = true;
    checkForLastName();
    checkForSelection();
    validateRadio();
    validateZipCode();
    validateEmail();
    validatePassword();
    return validation;
}
```

```html
<form onSubmit ="return runAll();">
    Please enter your name.
    <input type ="text" id="lastNameField">
    <br>
    <button>submit</button>
</form>
```

The individual functions are firing, but together they're not.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Do you mean that as for debugger, rulAll() is not called at all?

Answer (score 1):

I'm thinking the return command is causing the problem;  it is only valid within a function call

```
<form onSubmit ="return runAll();">
```

should be

```
<form onSubmit ="runAll()">
```

Answer (score 1):

I assume that each of the functions `checkForLastName`, `checkForSelection` ... return either `true` or `false` depending on their validation of the input their handling. So what you need is to check if one of them returns `false` to stop the submit. If my assumption is right use this:

```
function runAll() {
    // if not checkForLastName return false
    if(!checkForLastName()) return false;
    // if not ...
    if(!checkForSelection()) return false;
    if(!validateRadio()) return false;
    if(!validateZipCode()) return false;
    if(!validateEmail()) return false;
    if(!validatePassword()) return false;

    // then if all is good (none of them returned false), you can return true to submit
    return true;
}
```